# Not able to scroll in the Calendar Form (for day , month, year)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-android

I am trying to scroll a birth day Calendar for selecting day, month and year.
Each column can be scrolled separately.

I am not able to scroll and select a specific birth date e.g. Jan, 12, 1964

[image]

I have tried after getting the birth day Calendar

WebElement dayPicker = driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator(
    //                "new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().resourceIdMatches(\"//android.widget.NumberPicker[@index='0']\").flingForward()"));

```
daypicker.sendKeys("12"));  (for sample 12.Jan 1964) 


here is the error text resp. log which  I got in inteliJ:






org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: Could not parse UiSelector argument: unclosed paren in expression
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'MYHOST', ip: '192.168.227.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '10.0.2'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver
Capabilities {MobileCapabilityType.FULL_RESET: true, PlatformVersion: 9.0, app: D:\08_OSCA\APKs\aOS\1.0_115..., appActivity: net.myAPP.view...., appPackage: net.myAPP.int, appWaitActivity: net.myAPP.*, appWaitPackage: net.myAPP.int, databaseEnabled: false, desired: {MobileCapabilityType.FULL_RESET: true, PlatformVersion: 9.0, app: D:\08_OSCA\APKs\aOS\1.0_115..., appWaitActivity: net.myAPP.*, deviceName: Huawei Mate20, language: en, locale: US, noReset: false, platformName: android}, deviceManufacturer: samsung, deviceModel: SM-G950F, deviceName: ce031713636588a20c, deviceScreenSize: 1440x2960, deviceUDID: ce031713636588a20c, javascriptEnabled: true, language: en, locale: US, locationContextEnabled: false, networkConnectionEnabled: true, noReset: false, platform: LINUX, platformName: LINUX, platformVersion: 9, takesScreenshot: true, warnings: {}, webStorageEnabled: false}
Session ID: 7ce983d2-0d18-4627-8a24-7b7945a5fdfc
*** Element info: {Using=-android uiautomator, value=new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().resourceIdMatches("//android.widget.NumberPicker[@index='0']").flingForward()}

    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:239)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:323)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElement(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:62)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElement(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.MobileBy.findElement(MobileBy.java:63)
    at io.appium.java_client.MobileBy$ByAndroidUIAutomator.findElement(MobileBy.java:282)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:315)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElement(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:58)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElement(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at screens.RegistrationScreen.select_Day(RegistrationScreen.java:138)
    at tests.registration.Register_Tests.TC_2292_RegisterNewUser(Register_Tests.java:120)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:73)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)
```

Thanks for any Support

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the exception, given element doesn't have the scrollable = true.

Instead, you can do set the date using below code

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.NumberPicker[@index='0']//android.widget.EditText[@index=1]")).sendKeys("12");

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.NumberPicker[@index='1']//android.widget.EditText[@index=1]")).sendKeys("Jan");

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.NumberPicker[@index='2']//android.widget.EditText[@index=1]")).sendKeys("2019");

driver.findElement(By.id("android:id/button1")).click();
```

Try this

Comment: thanks but it does not work. it does not chnage teh value to sendkeys 12, Jan, 2019 it remain on 3, Jun 2019
But you are right the first and second column have the Attribute Scrollable = False
But the third one has it true
is it possibile only scroll teh third column , if so then I can ask developer to put the other also to true
How about if I want only scroll

Comment: you can do this in multiple ways, try other things also